# Why do free -m and htop show different amounts of total memory?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, cache, memcached, htop

When I run `free -m`, I get different data from when I use `htop`.

`free -m`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            992         396         149          23         446         392
Swap:             0           0           0
```

`htop`:

```
Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||456        ]
```

`htop` screenshot:
https://gyazo.com/71cbb11b6cf2609082a06a7c5acf1aaf

Information:

- RAM: 1GB
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3

I know for a fact that I have 1GB of total RAM, showing that `free -m` is accurate with that. But how come `htop` claims that the max RAM is only about 512MB? I can say that I had 512MB until I upgraded to 1GB about 12 hours ago. I did reinstall `htop` but that didn't help; I still got the same results. So why is it that `free -m` claims that I have 992MB total RAM and `htop` claims that I have about 512MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are misinterpreting what htop is telling you, I don't see anywhere that htop says you only have 512MB of memory. You can get a definitive answer by configuring htop to display numbers rather than a graph. 
Go to settings F2 -> Meters -> Memory and then press the space bar. This will rotate through the memory display options, one of which is text e.g.

```
Mem:31.4G used 6.71G buffers 4.15M cache: 2.0G
```